# Asus ROG GL702VM ACPI Keyboard Backlight

Tags: keyboard, asus, keyboard-backlight

i'm trying to power on the keyboard backlight on my new laptop but every attempt has miserably failed.
I've tried to use xset but nothing happens. I've been able to manually set the capslock led on/off but nothing else since i added acpi_osi= in my grub configuration. At least before that i could see the asus_airplane folder under /sys/class/leds and i could set it on/off too (now its gone) but the main backlight of the keyboard seems completely missing (i've seen the folder kbd_backlight referred in many forums).

Any ideas? Is possible the kernel has no clue my keyboard can do that?
Thanks a lot, i wish i won't be forced to reinstall windows and virtualize ubuntu again :(

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: So sorry for the long long time, frankly i moved back to windows after few hours i think, i i've even forgotten the request. Anyway i've never found a solution even if i retried not so long time ago! And have to say, Windows 10 sucks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Toshiba laptop too. I searched the internet for weeks for a possible solution. Replacing **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""** with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off"** in grub configuration fixed the keyboard backlight issue, but after disabling acpi, the usb-mouse, network card, FN keys didn’t work. Not even the laptop’s mouse pad worked! So, be careful with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off"**. If we can find a way to disable acpi and still have everything else working, that would be the answer to this problem.

Comment: Wow. I certainly won't use that solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as you said it would be a nightmare with the entire PC then, not a good idea after all!